# Tween class help for ActionScript 3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, google-play-games

I'm trying to make my code where my avatar (thing you move with your finger) move by a tween because when you put your finger on it works but when you take it off and put it back on the avatar will instantly teleport to my finger and I want him to move to it. Please inform me what I've done wrong and what I can improve to make this work.(this is in a class which is why I use public )

```
public var lastPosX:Number;  public var lastPosY:Number;

    public function onTouchBegin (e:TouchEvent):void {
        var newPosX:Number = avatar.x; //the point of x your finger is
        var newPosY:Number = avatar.y; //the point of y your finger is
        //checks for first time putting finger down
        if ( isNaN(lastPosX)) {
            avatar.x = e.stageX;
            avatar.y = e.stageY;
            //x and y values = to your finger
        }
        else {
            var myTweenX:Tween = new Tween(avatar, "x", Strong.easeOut, lastPosX, newPosX, 5, true);
            var myTweenY:Tween = new Tween(avatar, "y", Strong.easeOut, lastPosY, newPosY, 5, true);
            //makes the avatar move to your finger when u lift your finger off and on
        }

    }
    public function onTouchMove (e:TouchEvent):void {
        avatar.x = e.stageX;
        avatar.y = e.stageY;
        //x and y values = to your finger
    }

    public function onTouchFinish (e:TouchEvent):void {
        avatar.x = e.stageX;
        avatar.y = e.stageY;
        lastPosX = avatar.x;
        lastPosY = avatar.y;
        //x and y values = to your finger
        //Defines x and y value of finger

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you develope game, Tween isn't good choice for updating position for avatar. Create main gaming loop, and update position for the avatar in `onTouchBegin`and correct position in `onTouchMove`. [This tutorial](http://asgamer.com/2009/as3-character-movement-following-mouse-with-easing) should help you. In another way, you are forced to spawn new Tweens in `onTouchMove`.

Comment: Hi thanks so much could u give me a hint on what to do cause in the code but i get your concept so thanks ( im very new to flash as ive been coding on other things and im just exploring THANKS :D)

Answer (score 0):

[image: code]

switch for action up and down we have no default bocoz write now dont want to do only these 2 things
first 2 line gives touch coordinate

playable area is set such that only in that area touch works
roughly lower fourth area is occupid by character so takinh /4